# How can I extract exif data from a THM file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, exif

I'm trying to view the media track creation date in the exif data of a THM file. Using the command line utility exiftool, I am able to see this property. How can I see it using objective c?

This is what I've tried so far.

```
 [self downloadImageWithURL:[candidateVideo objectForKey:@"thmURL"] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data) {
            if (succeeded) {
                CGImageSourceRef source=CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data,NULL);
                NSDictionary* metaData=(__bridge NSDictionary*)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
                NSMutableDictionary* metaDataMutable=[metaData mutableCopy];
                    //recalculate validity with the images exif data
                NSMutableDictionary *EXIFDictionary = [[metaDataMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy];
                NSLog(@"wut");

            }
        }];
```

But my EXIFDictionary is nil.

I've also tried this and my dictionary has some key value pairs but there are only 3 and they are not what I need. I've tried using `UIIMageJPEGRepresenation()` and `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` to no avail. Too bad there is no `UIImageTHMRepresentation()`...

```
[self downloadImageWithURL:[candidateVideo objectForKey:@"thmURL"] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data) {
            if (succeeded) {
                    UIImage* thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                NSData* pngData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail,1.0);
                CGImageSourceRef source=CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)pngData,NULL);
                NSDictionary* metaData=(__bridge NSDictionary*)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
                NSMutableDictionary* metaDataMutable=[metaData mutableCopy];
                    //recalculate validity with the images exif data
                NSMutableDictionary *EXIFDictionary = [[metaDataMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy];
                NSLog(@"wut");

            }
        }];
```

Comment: Can you share a link to a file so we can take a look? Also, can you tell us where it's going wrong? `source`? `metaData`? Is there anything in `metaData` at all?

Comment: BTW, in your first code sample, don't forget to `CFRelease` the `source`. And, if using ARC, do `__bridge_transfer` of the `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` rather than just `__bridge` (or use `CFBridgingRelease`). If you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu in Xcode), it will probably point out these Core Foundation memory issues.

Comment: BTW, I might suggest that your attempt to round-trip the image through `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is going in the wrong direction, because it my experience, that's an excellent way to strip meta data. lol.

Comment: Yes round tripping seems to  be stripping data. I will update with more information.